# Getting File Names from Post

Tags: jquery, post

Sorry don't fully understand what is happening but will try to explain, want to send a file name using post in jquery but can not use dashes or file extension when it comes through the array.

In the HTML file passing the value using filename_

```
<div id="filename_file-name.txt"></div>
```

In the PHP file, trying to get the part of the array with the value of file-name.txt

```
$thefilename_array = $_POST['filename'];
$key = 0;
$the_selected_filename_from_array = $thefilename_array[$key];
```

This actually works if the filename is formatted without dashes like filename and not file-name.txt

This is what I'm trying to get

```
Array
(
    [0] => file-name.txt
)
```

Thanks for any help, will try to explain more if it is unclear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How are you posting the data?

Comment: `$_POST` contains data from form fields, i.e. `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements. Not `<div>` elements.

Comment: Yes that is correct, $_POST is for that, but the problem I'm having is I can send the value "myfile.txt" but not "my-file.txt" the dash in the name causes the value not to be sent to the php script on the server for processing, the value is just blank. I'm not sure if I'm making sense "mypicture.jpg" works but "my-picture.jpg" does not. Thanks for helping me on this.

Comment: Finding out others are having the same problem. I'm figuring out the because I'm using a ID property <div id="filename_"></div> that the addition of hyphens is causing json to subtract the value ex:<div id="filename_my-file.jpg"></div> , that's why when there are no hyphens the value passes through just fine. Maybe there is a easy way to escape the value so that the name of the file "my-file.jpg" get posted through and sent to the server so it can be retrieved with $_POST. Thanks for any help you can provide or point me to some articles that may help.